# How do I get started using Cygwin for C# development?

Tags: c#, windows, cygwin

I'm coming from Linux, and I want to try to learn some C# development.

But I'm partial to the command line and using Vim. Is it easy to set up Cygwin to run the `csc` compiler from the command line and to edit C# files directly in the console with Vim?

I downloaded SharpDevelop, but I would really like to give console-style C# development a try.

Specifically, how do I set up the PATH (is there an equivalent to .bash_profile?) so that I can run csc and vim from the Windows Console?

I'm running Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give [VsVim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329) a try. With C#, you'll thank yourself for sticking with Visual Studio.

Comment: Written by none other than [@JaredPar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar).

Comment: How painful is it to forgo the IDE in C# development?

Comment: @dan: It largely depends on your coding style, along with how experienced you are with the BCL.

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically, how do I set up the PATH (is there an equivalent to .bash_profile?) so that I can run csc and vim from the Windows Console?

Exactly like in linux. The only difference, IIRC, is that you use `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile`. Edit (or create) the file in your **cygwin** user's home directory (`~/`) and write the usual `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/other/bin` lines.

http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html

Answer (score 1):

I love VsVim, as suggested by Joel.  But you said you want to try without Visual Studio, so here:

`vim` integrates well with gnu `make`, and writing makefiles for C# programs is quite simple.

Just be careful about tabs vs spaces, same as on Linux (and like I'm not doing on SO, since getting tabs in HTML code blocks is hard).  You'll just need a rule along the lines of:

```
myapp.exe : mymain.cs myhelpers.cs mydialog.cs
    csc.exe /o /out:$@ $^
```

Then from inside `vim`, you can just use the `:make` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe");
        pInfo.Arguments = "-i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -";
```

if cygwin is installed on C:\